# Youtube Data API V3 Direct Video Upload authorization

Tags: .net, youtube-data-api

I have an application which uploads videos on youtube. Using Data API V2, I only ask users to provide youtube user name and password and app then generates and uploads the videos on youtube. My Users are used to this behavior. Now I am trying to move to V3 but unable to find the exact same authorizatin mechanism in V3. Is there something I am missing or I have to change my approach. My App is a WPF application.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What kind of security do you use. If you uses username/password then it is deprecated and you hade to use oauth2 instead.
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Comment: yup I am using username/password. So it means I am no longer able to simply port my code from V2 to V3 without my users envolvement?

Comment: Im afraid not. The oauth2 is in short that the client login through google and then approve your application to be used with there credentials. and you have to retrive the credentials through google when the client wants to upload a video or edit i playlist etc.

Comment: The main reason for this is to remove apps that steals the clients username/password, so with oauth2 they don't need to pass through 3rd parties applications.